# BindingList<T> is not showing up in the datagridview it is bound too

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I've looked all over and can't seem to figure out why my c# windows form application isn't working.

So I have a Item class with some private members:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string name_;

    public string name { 
        get { return name_;}
        set
        {
            name_ = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that holds the Bindinglist of Items

```
public class ItemList
{
    public BindingList<Item> listItems { get; set; }

    // Default constructor
    public ItemList()
    {
        listItems = new BindingList<Item>();
    }
    public BindingList<Item> returnList()
    {
        return listItems;
    }
    public void addItem(Item newItem)
    {
        listItems.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Then I have a BindingSource that is linked from the listItems to the datagridview

The issue is that I am adding Items to listItems and they are not showing up in the datagridview. The datagridview is seeing all of my data members and makes columns for them, but it isn't showing the items.

Comment: 1. Why do you have a returnList() and a listItems{ get; }?

2. Can you show us the code you are using to bind the list?

Comment: I have the bindingList in a separate file but in the same namespace. I guess I don't really need the returnList() since it's public. I bound it in the settings of the [Design] window, but here is what I see in the .Designer.cs file 'this.itemListBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.itemListBindingSource)).BeginInit();'   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.itemListBindingSource;

Comment: @Hans here is the binding source code '// 
            // itemListBindingSource
            // 
            this.itemListBindingSource.DataMember = "listItems";
            this.itemListBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(ItemQuoter.ItemList);
            this.itemListBindingSource.CurrentChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.itemListBindingSource_CurrentChanged);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i have a feeling you have been adding the ItemList instance instead of listItems.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemList list = new ItemList();
        list.listItems.Add(new Item() { name = "Sample" });
        list.listItems.Add(new Item() { name = "Sample" });
        list.listItems.Add(new Item() { name = "Sample" });
        list.listItems.Add(new Item() { name = "Sample" });
        list.listItems.Add(new Item() { name = "Sample" });
        list.listItems.Add(new Item() { name = "Sample" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list.listItems;

    }
}

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string name_;

    public string name
    {
        get { return name_; }
        set
        {
            name_ = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public class ItemList
{
    public BindingList<Item> listItems { get; set; }

    // Default constructor 
    public ItemList()
    {
        listItems = new BindingList<Item>();
    }
    public BindingList<Item> returnList()
    {
        return listItems;
    }
    public void addItem(Item newItem)
    {
        listItems.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```